# FFMPEG Subtitle Burning - Make Them Look Like Youtube Captions

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I want to burn subtitles into videos and make them look as close to the YouTube captions as possible.  I've gotten pretty close with the following:

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEOFILE.mkv -vf subtitles="f=SUBSFILE.vtt:force_style='FontName=Arial,FontSize=14,OutlineColour=&H55000000,BorderStyle=3,WrapStyle=2'" -y ENCODED-WITH-SUBS.mp4
```

#### 1.  The major thing I want to fix in the above command is that when there are multiple lines, the backgrounds overlap.

[image]

If you look at captions on YouTube there is always a nice small amount of space between the backgrounds.

[image]

#### 2. The second thing I'd like to do is make the corners of the backgrounds rounded if possible.

I've looked through the documentation but I'm hoping I missed something.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: For #1, a possible workaround is to extract an .srt file from the .mkv, edit it to increase line spacing (If I recall correctly, .srt subtitles should hold positioning info), and burn that back in. Alternatively, decreasing the font size _might_ work?

Comment: I don't want to decrease the font size, it's a good size for visibility right now.  Not sure what you mean about extracting an srt, I have the subtitle file and the video separately in this scenario.

Comment: @ecube SRT subtitles do NOT hold positioning info.